# Mac: "command" file extension can have what scripts?

Tags: macos, shell-script

I have `myname.command` script on OSX 10.8 from some app. It has Bash script, with signature (she-bang).

What other script formats can be inside `*.command` files? Maybe AppleScript or some others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `unix/linux` world (afaik mac is running a `unix` variant) you wouldn't need any file extensions for programs, but it's good practice to give `bash` scripts the `.sh`, python scripts the `.py`, perl the `.pl` (etc.) extension for humans to identify those scripts without viewing the script checking the she-bang line. (I don't know if there are specific extensions for mac)

The important part is the executable flag `chmod +x ./myscript.sh` which marks the file as a program that can be executed.

The `she-bang` line is the first line in a file and starts with `#!` followed by the fullpath pointing to an executable `/usr/bin/bash`, `/usr/bin/perl`, `/usr/bin/python`.

On some Unix/Linux installations it could be possible that `python`, `bash`or any program is not located in `/usr/bin/` but in `/opt/python3.6` so the she-bang `#! /usr/bin/python` wouldn't start the program. So basically it's another good practice to start she-bang line with `#!/usr/bin/env` followed by the program you want to start ie. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

This will look into the environment vars ([PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Unix_2)) for that given program.

Comment: Good text, but wanted to know: which scripts can be inside Mac's .command files. Seems only Bash. I mean filese with .command suffix.

Comment: a `.command` file is just a file type that has been associated with the Terminal app, so when you double-click on it, the Finder launches Terminal, and passes it the file. .. So just try `perl`, `awk` or `python` whatever is installed on your system and look for a hello world example.